# SVN - working on files being committed

Tags: svn

Is it okay to work on the files being checked in during svn commit? Sometimes I have seen "Svn Locked Directories" in the IDE, but not always. As far as I understood, svn creates a copy of the files to be committed and so if I continue working on the files being committed, that wouldn't be a problem right? Yes, nothing wrong in waiting till the check in is done; just curious to know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked to SVN 1.7 code. Before commit is locks wc.db (creates a record in WC_LOCK table). Then is sends deltas between your local files and pristine files (from .svn/pristine, i.e. file contents before change), taking care about keywords- and eols-backtranslation. And after all it unlocks wc.db (I skipped non-interesting parts of the commit process).

So

- "Svn Locked Directories" can be explained by WC_LOCK record (your IDE checks it before every write operation on the working copy). And you cannot modify your local files.
- You can't modify files while committing because SVN uses them to create commit instead of saving somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SVN you are using, but as far as I know, it will commit them one by one, so if you keep working on one, before it is committed those changes would be committed as well.